# Poco+OpenSSL, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: windows, openssl, poco

Problem with Poco library (poco-1.9.0-all) and OpenSSL (v1.1.0h from slproweb site).
I can't establish a secure connection with any site.

Simple code:

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
Poco::Net::Context* pCtx = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage::TLSV1_2_CLIENT_USE, "", "cacert.pem", "", Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, false);
Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession cs("ya.ru", 443, pCtx);

Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/?encoding=text", Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
Poco::Net::HTTPResponse resp;

try
{
    Poco::Net::WebSocket sock(cs, req, resp);
}
catch (Poco::Net::SSLException& e)
{
    cout << "ssl exception: " << e.displayText() << endl;
}
catch (...)
{
}
```

I get a exception from the poco library: 'SSL Exception: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed'.
File cacert.pem downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

OpenSSL reads it without errors by SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file function in Poco::Net::Context::init(const Params& params).

If I specify the verification mode VERIFY_NONE in Poco::Net::Context constructor - connection passes without problems.

Maybe I'm setting the wrong parameters in Poco::Net::Context constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exception: SSL Exception: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed. Changing the order of constructor Poco::Net::Context constructor arguments helps:

```
Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "cacert.pem", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
```

cacert.pem it is the root CA certificate file and should be passed as caLocation argument.

Comment: Hey, how did you optain the cacert.pem file? Can you somehow use the systems certificates?